# SQL injection simulation example

Tags: joomla, sql-injection, code-injection

I try to simulate an sql injection within a joomla module, but I it not working. I did some debug in the joomla and I arrive to the following problem.

The code works well in php admin:

```
SELECT cd.*, cc.title AS category_name, cc.description AS category_description, cc.image AS category_image, CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(cd.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(':', cd.id, cd.alias) ELSE cd.id END as slug, CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(cc.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(':', cc.id, cc.alias) ELSE cc.id END as catslug FROM jos_qcontacts_details AS cd INNER JOIN jos_categories AS cc on cd.catid = cc.id WHERE cc.published = 1 AND cd.published = 1 AND cc.access <= 0 AND cd.access <= 0 ORDER BY 1 , cd.ordering;/*!DELETE*/ FROM jos_users where id=64--
```

But it doesn't work in joomla, I debug the execution to the function in mysqli.php:

```
function query()
    {

        // Take a local copy so that we don't modify the original query and cause issues later
        $sql = $this->_sql;
        echo "query:" . $sql;

        $this->_cursor = mysqli_query( $this->_resource, $sql );

        return $this->_cursor;
    }
```

The problem is that the sql query in phpmyadmin but it isn't working in `mysqli_query( $this->_resource, $sql );`.
I am using joomla 1.5 because this is just a simulation.

If you have some idea please share with me. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to execute *multiple statements* with mysqli is with [`mysqli_multi_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php):

> *Multiple statements or multi queries must be executed with `mysqli_multi_query()`.* The individual statements of the statement string are separated by semicolon. Then, all result sets returned by the executed statements must be fetched.
>
> ..
>
> **Security considerations**
>
> *The API functions `mysqli_query()` and `mysqli_real_query()` do not set a connection flag necessary for activating multi queries in the server.* An extra API call is used for multiple statements to reduce the likeliness of accidental SQL injection attacks. An attacker may try to add statements such as `; DROP DATABASE` mysql or `; SELECT SLEEP(999)`. If the attacker succeeds in adding SQL to the statement string but mysqli_multi_query is not used, the server will not execute the second, injected and malicious SQL statement.

As such, the standard `mysqli_query` call should be safe from injecting *secondary* statements.

Comment: Not that I know of, for *secondary statement* injection - but I always use placeholders, limit permissions, and don't otherwise concern myself with such matters. Other injection vectors still apply.

Comment: thank you, you helped me a lot, I learn a new prevention. You have an idea for possibly attack in this case ?

Comment: I have changed the database controller to mysql which is the same just uses the mysql_query() function instead of mysqli_query() and I have the same response, the user is there, nothing happened.

Comment: @flatronka I believe mysql_query has the same default of not allowing multiple statements. Use `mysqli_multiple_query` to "enable" this form of SQL injection.